# Digitizing in stream mode in QGIS using a tablet

Tags: qgis, digitizing, tablet

How can I digitize in stream mode in QGIS, using a wacom cintiq tablet?

Freehand it's no use. I need something like MNDR stream digitizing extension for ArcView 3.x, which allows continuous tracing, append polygons, split features, etc.

Comment: I am sitting with the same problem and would also like to know whether any plugins are available for this in 2017.

Comment: Qt apparently offers some support for the tablet https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-tablet-example.html That would require some investigations.

Comment: What is 'MNDR'?   Maybe https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177668/capturing-mouse-movement-on-qgsmapcanvas could help with stream digitizing.

Comment: This is quite an old question, nowadays options for digitizing on tablet are much improved and, as I understand, streaming (adding vertices automatically while changing location on a device) is possible. For example, Qfield allows streaming and editing of layers on a tablet, but one could also look at Collector for ArcGIS or NEXTGIS  for data collection and digitizing.

Comment: The ability to digitize in streaming mode appeared in QGIS 3.20 version (Odense). You need to press the R key during digitizing to switch the treaming mode ON or OFF. https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-streaming-digitizing-mode

Answer (score 3):

QGIS as of version 3.20 supports stream digitizing. I have not tested it on a tablet though.

[image]