# Capturing mouse movement on QgsMapCanvas?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I have a python app that uses QgsMapCanvas as map display. I put it inside a QWidget, which is then inside another control. The problem is that there seems to be no way of tracking mouse move event on the QgsMapCanvas itself. I've tried connect as below:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.canvas, QtCore.SIGNAL("mouseMoveEvent()"), self.canvasMoveEvent)
```

it doesn't trigger that event when the mouse is moving inside the canvas area.

How do I trap mouse movement inside a QgsMapCanvas in the above setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### QgsMapTool

You probably want to implement a [`QgsMapTool` and set this as the active map tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/how-to-programatically-check-for-a-mouse-click-in-qgis).

This offers several methods which you can implement to react

- `canvasMoveEvent`
- `canvasPressEvent`
- `canvasReleaseEvent`
- `canvasDoubleClickEvent`
- [and some more](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html)

You will then have to do

```
canvas.setMapTool( yourmaptool )
```

to make it active.

### xyCoordinates event

If you really need to get the information from outside a map tool, you can connect to the `xyCoordinates` event

```
canvas.xyCoordinates.connect( self.canvasMoveEvent )
```

### eventFilter

Or install an [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on the map canvas. This is a very mighty Qt approach, it's the (non-elegant) sledgehammer to do things but it's the way to go if you need to even modify the mouse events before they are further processed by other tools.