# Capture mouse movement on the map

Tags: openlayers

I have found this [Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177668/capture-mouse-movement-on-qgsmapcanvas) for capturing mouse movement on the map, but I'm not using python for this project, I use `openlayers3`.

I would like someone to explain to me how can I capture mouse movement on the map with `openlayers3`, basically map will follow users interaction whit the map. Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/6uo6bg3p/1/) example of the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listen for pointermove event on map object:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    // When user was dragging map, then coordinates didn't change and there's
    // no need to continue
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }
    // You can access coordinates from evt.coordinate now
});
```